# ThinkingSphinx::OutOfBoundsError configuration confusion

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Hitting an OutOfBoundsError as a consequence of misunderstanding the proper configuration syntax (which may also be a by-product of legacy syntax).

The [manual](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/searching.html#pagination)  suggests a Class search taking on WillPaginate styled parameters.  Having many fields to draw from, the model is defined as

```
class AziendaSearch < BaseSearch
  set_per_page 10000
  accept :terms
end
```

the set_per_page was put at a high level because if I set it at the target of 100, the will_paginate links do not show up.

the controller may be excessively convoluted to include the ordering parameter, and thus result in a two-step process:

```
@azienda_search = AziendaSearch.new params
@results = @azienda_search.search
@aziendas = Azienda.order('province_id ASC').where('id IN (?)', @results).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 100
```

the view paginates on the basis of @aziendas:

```
<%= will_paginate @aziendas, :previous_label => "precedente ", :next_label => " successiva" %>
```

My suspicion is that the search model is not properly set, but the syntax is not obvious to me given the manual's indications. `page params[:page]` certainly does not work...

**Update**
`BaseSearch` is a [Sphinx method](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/web/searchadapters.html#sphinxcontrib.websupport.search.BaseSearch) and was in fact inherited from an older version of this applications (rails2.x...).  So this may be hanging around creating all sort of syntaxic confusion.

In fact, following the manual, I am now fully uncertain as to how to best makes these statements. Should a seperate class be defined for AziendaSearch ? If not, where should the `Azienda.search` bloc be invoked... in the controller as such?

```
@azienda_search = Azienda.search(
  :max_matches => 100_000,
  :page        => params[:page],
  :per_page    => 100,
  :order       => "province_id ASC"
  )
@results = @azienda_search.search
```

Comment: Your link for BaseSearch is to a different Sphinx project (one that's focused on documentation, not full-text search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `BaseSearch` is doing with `set_per_page` (that's certainly not a Thinking Sphinx method), but it's worth noting that Sphinx defaults to a maximum of 1000 records. [It is possible to configure Sphinx to return more](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/advanced_config.html#large-result-sets), though - you need to set max_matches in your `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` to your preferred limit (per environment):

```
production:
  max_matches: 100000
```

And also set the limit on the relevant search requests:

```
Azienda.search(
  :max_matches => 100_000,
  :page        => params[:page],
  :per_page    => 100
)
```

As for the doubled queries… if you add `province_id` as an attribute in your index definition, you'll be able to [order search queries](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/searching.html#sorting) by it.

```
# in your Azienda index definition:
has province_id

# And then when searching:
Azienda.search(
  params[:azienda_search][:terms],
  :max_matches => 100_000,
  :page        => params[:page],
  :per_page    => 100,
  :order       => "province_id ASC"
)
```

Comment: Question updated as semantics are gummed up with legacy [ahem] thinking...

Comment: To address your updated question: you can use the Azienda.search call as a single invocation that replaces the three lines you previously had. So, the search call can be assigned to the `@aziendas` instance variable.

Comment: oddly enough I had tried that.  But got a `undefined local variable or method 'params' ` error for the page symbol...

Comment: This is in your controller? I would expect params to exist there.

Comment: No, that was in the model inheriting from BaseSearch.  I've moved the logic completely to the controller, added `:terms       => params[:azienda_search][:terms],`the console readout returns `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "azienda_search"=>{"terms"=>"pinerolo"}}` but the Sphinx query is not being very selective `Sphinx Query (92.2ms)  SELECT * FROM 'azienda_core' WHERE 'sphinx_deleted' = 0 LIMIT 0, 100 OPTION max_matches=100000` and returns all records. Pagination & ordering function as hoped. note:  `@aziendas =   Azienda.search params[:azienda_search][:terms] ( [...]` generates a syntaxic error.

Comment: I've updated the syntax in my answer with the search keyword, which should work.